# Remove a value from a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I have the following code which when a button is clicked checks to see the previous value stored and concatenates it with the new value - essentially to get a long list of latitudes and longitudes.

(arrayvalues is declared globally)

```
var previousvalues = document.getElementsByName('arrayvalues')[0].value

arrayvalues = previousvalues + latitude+ "," + longitude+"##";
//alert(arrayvalues);
document.getElementById("arrayvalues").value = arrayvalues;
```

The document.getElementById stores the new value here:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="arrayvalues" id="arrayvalues" />
```

However the issue I am having is the user can at any point undo their last click meaning the last latitude and longitude values stored need removing. How can I go about doing this the way I have coded it?

Comment: from your code it looks like you have a string moreso than an array.

Comment: Protip: I recommend not storing application state in HTML elements. Store these values in JavaScript and update them from HTML when needed. Someday you're going to want to access these values or change them and the HTML wont be around, and then you'll have to load the elements just to get at the state because you have 10K lines of code assuming state in DOM.

Comment: You should store the lat/long in a data structure instead of a string, such as an array, which holds objects contacting each lat/long pair. Then when you output the values to the user, you simply combine the values into the string you want the user to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `pop` method available for JavaScript arrays, which will remove the last stored element. Here's a brief tutorial on `pop()`:

So if your array is the following:

```
var coords = [[lat1,long1],[lat2,long2],[lat3,long3]]
```

Running `coords.pop()` will result in `coords` being the following:

```
 [[lat1,long1],[lat2,long2]]
```

Comment: Thanks - took a bit of tweaking of my initial code but got there eventually